# Swiper JS slider with Image Comparison Slider for each slider item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have used Swiper JS library for Image slider in a project and for each slider item there is an image comparison slider to show before and after results. Now, the problem is that when I move swiper slider with grab cursor left to right then it is conflicting with image comparison slider functionality. I have been learning a bit more about JavaScript. Here's the code:

**index.html**

```
<div class="slide-container swiper">
            <div class="slide-content">
                <div class="card-wrapper swiper-wrapper">
                    
                    <div class="card swiper-slide">
                        <div class="img-comp-container">
                            <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-img-border">
                              <img src="images/After-001.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay  ">
                              <img src="images/Before-001.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <span class="label label-before">Before</span>
                            <span class="label label-after">After</span>
                            
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card swiper-slide">
                        <div class="img-comp-container">
                            <div class="img-comp-img">
                              <img src="images/After-002.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
                              <img src="images/Before-002.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-overlay" id="boxOverlay">
                                <span class="label label-before">Before</span>
                                <span class="label label-after">After</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card swiper-slide">
                        <div class="img-comp-container">
                            <div class="img-comp-img">
                              <img src="images/After-003.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
                              <img src="images/Before-003.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <span class="label label-before">Before</span>
                            <span class="label label-after">After</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card swiper-slide">
                        <div class="img-comp-container">
                            <div class="img-comp-img">
                              <img src="images/After-004.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
                              <img src="images/Before-004.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <span class="label label-before">Before</span>
                            <span class="label label-after">After</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-navBtn"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-navBtn"></div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
```

**script.js**

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".slide-content", {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 25,
    loop: true,
    centerSlide: 'true',
    fade: 'true',
    grabCursor: 'true',
    allowTouchMove: true,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
      dynamicBullets: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },

    breakpoints:{
        0: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        520: {  
            slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        950: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
        },
    },
  });

  
  function initComparisons() {
    var x, i;
    var op = 0;
    /*find all elements with an "overlay" class:*/
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-comp-overlay");
    
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      /*once for each "overlay" element:
      pass the "overlay" element as a parameter when executing the compareImages function:*/
      compareImages(x[i]);
    }
    function compareImages(img) {
      var slider, img, clicked = 0, w, h;
      /*get the width and height of the img element*/
      w = img.offsetWidth;
      h = img.offsetHeight;
      /*set the width of the img element to 50%:*/
      img.style.width = (w / 2) + "px";
      /*create slider:*/
      slider = document.createElement("DIV");
      slider.setAttribute("class", "img-comp-slider");
      
      /*insert slider*/
      img.parentElement.insertBefore(slider, img);
      /*position the slider in the middle:*/
      slider.style.top = (h / 2) - (slider.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
      slider.style.left = (w / 2) - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
      
      /*execute a function when the mouse button is pressed:*/
      slider.addEventListener("mousedown", slideReady);
      /*and another function when the mouse button is released:*/
      window.addEventListener("mouseup", slideFinish);
      /*or touched (for touch screens:*/
      slider.addEventListener("touchstart", slideReady);
      /*and released (for touch screens:*/
      window.addEventListener("touchend", slideFinish);
      function slideReady(e) {

        
        /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
        e.preventDefault();
        /*the slider is now clicked and ready to move:*/
        clicked = 1;
        /*execute a function when the slider is moved:*/
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", slideMove);
        window.addEventListener("touchmove", slideMove);

      }
      function slideFinish() {
        /*the slider is no longer clicked:*/
        clicked = 0;
        
      }
      function slideMove(e) {
        //document.getElementById("boxOverlay").style.opacity=op;
        
        var pos;
        /*if the slider is no longer clicked, exit this function:*/
        if (clicked == 0) return false;
        /*get the cursor's x position:*/
        pos = getCursorPos(e)
        /*prevent the slider from being positioned outside the image:*/
        if (pos < 0) pos = 0 + 20;
        if (pos > w) pos = w - 20;
        /*execute a function that will resize the overlay image according to the cursor:*/
        slide(pos);
      }
      function getCursorPos(e) {
        var a, x = 0;
        e = (e.changedTouches) ? e.changedTouches[0] : e;
        /*get the x positions of the image:*/
        a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
        /*calculate the cursor's x coordinate, relative to the image:*/
        x = e.pageX - a.left;
        /*consider any page scrolling:*/
        x = x - window.pageXOffset;
        return x;
      }
      function slide(x) {
        /*resize the image:*/
        img.style.width = x + "px";
        /*position the slider:*/
        slider.style.left = img.offsetWidth - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
        
      }
    }
  }

  /*Execute a function that will execute an image compare function for each element with the img-comp-overlay class:*/
  initComparisons();


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.img-comp-slider').hover(
      function() { swiper.allowTouchMove = false;
      $('.swiper-wrapper').addClass( "disabled" ); 
       },
      function(e){ swiper.allowTouchMove = true;
        $('.swiper-wrapper').addClass( "disabled" ); 
      }
    );
});
```

**style.css**

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
.slide-container{
  max-width: 1240px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
.slide-content{
  margin: 0 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.card{
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: transparent;
  
}

.swiper-navBtn{
  color: #6E93f7;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
.swiper-navBtn:hover{
  color: #4070F4;
}
.swiper-navBtn::before,
.swiper-navBtn::after{
  font-size: 35px;
}
.swiper-button-next{
  right: 0;
}
.swiper-button-prev{
  left: 0;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet{
  background-color: #6E93f7;
  opacity: 1;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active{
  background-color: #4070F4;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .slide-content{
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
  .swiper-navBtn{
    display: none;
  }
}


.img-comp-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px; 
  height: 400px !important; /* should be same as images */
  margin: 0px 20px;
  
}


.img-comp-img {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  
}

.img-comp-img img {
  display:block;
  /* vertical-align:middle; */
  width: 320px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
}

.img-comp-overlay {
    /* border-right: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255); */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  /* .img-comp-img-border:before {
    content: attr(data-after);; 
    display: block; 
    height: 5px; 
    width: 5px; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 155px; 
    top: 0; 
    background: #f00; 
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
  } */


.img-comp-slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:30;
  /*set the appearance of the slider:*/
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("../images/image.png");
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-comp-slider:focus .box-overlay{
    opacity: 0;
}

.box-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 25;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    opacity: 0;
  }

.img-comp-container:hover .box-overlay{
    opacity: 1;
}

.img-comp-container .label {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    padding: 12px 14px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    user-select: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(.68,.26,.58,1.22);
  }
  .img-comp-container:hover .label {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .img-comp-container .label.label-before {
    left: 1rem;
  }
  .img-comp-container .label.label-after {
    right: 1rem;
  }
```

I have tried to resolve this issue and added functionality with JQuery that if mouse hover over on comparison slider then swiper js sliding should be disabled but it is not working smoothly. Please suggest possible solutions.